# Show $f(x)=\mu(B(x,r))$ is measurable, where $B(x,r)$ is a closed ball.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$ be a nonnegative regular Borel measure on $n$-dimensional Euclid space, and for any compact set $K$, $\mu(K)$ is finite. $B(x,r)$ is a closed ball with center on $x$ and radius $r$.
How to show that $f(x)=\mu\big(B(x,r)\big)$ is measurable?

The following is what I know:
For alocally compact Hausdorff space, any compact set will be closed. And Borel set surely contains all closed sets，so the $\mu(Κ)$ is admissible.

By the def of measurable, I guess I have to show that $f^{-1}(r，\infty]$ is a Borel set, for any real number $r$. So maybe I need to represent the set into union or intersection of some open or closed sets.
Maybe the regular Borel measure $\mu$ has the property: for any open set $E$, or $\mu(E)$ is finite, then $\mu(E)$ can be a sup of all compact sets $K$ contained in $E$, is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$E=\{(x,y):||x-y\|<r\}$ is an open set. So $\chi_E$ is measurable function of $(x,y)$. It is shown in the proof of Fubuni's Theorem that $\int \chi_E (x,y)d\mu(y)$ is a measurable function of $x$. But $\int \chi_E (x,y)d\mu(y)=\mu (B(x,r))$.

[If a Borel meaure on an Euclidean space is finite on compact sets then it is $\sigma-$ finite since $\{x:\|x\|\le n\}$ has finite measure for every $n$].

Comment: The Fubuni’s theorem need the measure is σ-finite.but the borel measure not necessarily is a σ-finite.it seems not work.

Comment: Or I need retell the theorem for this condition,for we have had a σ-finite measure:Lebesgue measure.

Comment: If a Borel meaure on an Euclidean space is finite on compact sets then it is $\sigma-$ finite since $\{x:\|x\|\le n\}$ has finite measure for every $n$. @CharlesTaylor